# Can game data be transferred to another game cartridge?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, nintendogs-and-cats

Okay,

This may have been answered already, but I need to know the answer before I end up crying in a ball of tears.

Apparently, I kind of lost my Nintendogs 3DS game cartridge... It's somewhere, in my house. I looked high and low, but still can't find it. It showed me streetpassing with my sister for the game from 11/14/13 - 01/22/14. After that, I haven't recieved anymore passes (and the Nintendogs can go up to 10, and I've only done 6.)

What I want to know, if I bought a digital copy or a another physical copy, would my game data from my SD card be able to transfer over? Or am I doomed to have to restart everything?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, save data for a physical copy of a 3DS game is kept on the cartridge, not the SD card. So without the old cartridge, there is no way to recover your save data.

Comment: Ahhh, I thought so =(