# What happened to my Nintendogs and Cats save file?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

Is there a way to have extra save files on my 3DS for nintendogs + cats?

Yesterday I put the game in my 3DS, and, without pressing any buttons, some ugly mutt came up and it was the only dog in the house and hotel. It definitely was not one of the dogs I had adopted previously.

I am really worried about my other dogs as I worked very hard to get my robodog. Is there a place where my actual save data is, or are these dogs lost forever?

Comment: I read this one https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157043/can-game-data-be-transferred-to-another-game-cartridge?rq=1 and I am not sure if theses are the same becouse I understood https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157043/can-game-data-be-transferred-to-another-game-cartridge?rq=1 as the asker lost their game card and wanted to know if they would have to restart everything if they brought a new one and mine is about what happend to my game and how to save it ok? (P.s delete this comment after you understand the huge differences to theses simular questions ok?)

Comment: Looks like a corupted save to me :/

Answer (score 1):

There's no multiple save feature as far as I know. The save was most likely corrupted.

As to why it was corrupted...I have no clue, it doesn't seem right to just pop the card in the 3DS only to realize your save data was changed/deleted entirely.